# transform 2d canvas in 3d

Tags: javascript, three.js

I try to understand how [house or plan builder](https://www.roomsketcher.com/) work when you can draw a floorplan

How they transform 2d floor plan in 3d wall.

I made a small demo with 2d canvas line and I try to find out how to convert a 2d canvas line in 3d wall with three.js or any other webgl libraries.

```js
var canvas,
    context,
    dragging = false,
    dragStartLocation,
    snapshot;


function getCanvasCoordinates(event) {
    var x = event.clientX - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left,
        y = event.clientY - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top;

    return {x: x, y: y};
}

function takeSnapshot() {
    snapshot = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function restoreSnapshot() {
    context.putImageData(snapshot, 0, 0);
}


function drawLine(position) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(dragStartLocation.x, dragStartLocation.y);
    context.lineTo(position.x, position.y);
    context.stroke();
}

function dragStart(event) {
    dragging = true;
    dragStartLocation = getCanvasCoordinates(event);
    takeSnapshot();
}

function drag(event) {
    var position;
    if (dragging === true) {
        restoreSnapshot();
        position = getCanvasCoordinates(event);
        drawLine(position);
    }
}

function dragStop(event) {
    dragging = false;
    restoreSnapshot();
    var position = getCanvasCoordinates(event);
    drawLine(position);
}

function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.strokeStyle = 'purple';
    context.lineWidth = 6;
    context.lineCap = 'round';

    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', dragStart, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', drag, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', dragStop, false);
}

window.addEventListener('load', init, false);
```

```css
*{
  border:0;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

canvas{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left:100px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    
</head>

<body>
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="600"></canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

If anyone has tracks to do it ?

Comment: I guess you could take all vertices of the 2D plan and copy them, but setting the Z-coordinate of the vertices to something else.

Comment: they are not converting a 2d-model into a 3d model. They use the same description/collection of items to render both views, 2D and later 3D. Something like a list of: *"wall, that thick from point a to point b, window in said wall at xy model abc in dimensions w,h, ... furniture xyz at position xy facing to abc, ... doors, stairs, carpets, Models, materials, positions, dimensions, orientation, ..."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the source for this app:

https://github.com/furnishup/blueprint3d

They take the line segments and extrude the points into walls, cut holes into the walls for windows and doors, and triangulate the floor polygons.

http://furnishup.github.io/blueprint3d/example/

Hope it helps.